# Create Notification with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I tried to create a Notification with this Code:

```
private void setNotificationAlarm(Context context) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MyNotification.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);  

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 , pendingIntent);
    Log.d("ME", "Alarm started");
}

public class MyNotification extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d("ME", "Notification started");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Hello World!");

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

And here my Mainfest declaration:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyNotification"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
</receiver>
```

My problem now is, that the alarm is generated but the Notification isn't displayed. The BroadcastReceiver is declared in the mainfest file and there are no compiler or runtime errors.

My second problem is that `setLatestEventInfo` and `new Notification` Contructor are deprecated. What can I use instead of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to use

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)
```

instead of `getService`

Comment: BroadcastReceivers generally work on some action. Define an action that your broadcastreceiver will work with and then add that action to  the manifest & in the intent. More details [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 8):

you can use

`Intent switchIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);`

instead of using

`Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MyNotification.class);`

in here BROADCAST_ACTION is action that you are defining in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".MyNotification " android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your package.ANY_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

you can catch it by using that action name

```
public class MyNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String act = "your package.ANY_NAME";
        if(intent.getAction().equals(act)){

            //your code here
        }
}}
```

Comment: BROADCAST_ACTION = ??

Answer (score 3):

You use `Notification.Builder` to build the notification now and the pending intent needs to be `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`