# Notification not triggering

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I read almost 30 threads on stackoverflow and i'am not able to get this code work.. i need notification every day on 14 PM. I'am getting no erros in Logcat only "waitforAlarm result: some integer". I'am desperate...

Heres is my code:

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Notifications.class

```
public class Notifications extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icona, "huhu", System.currentTimeMillis());


    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "asdas", "huhu", contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

}

Main.class

public void AlarmMethod(){

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Notifications.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    //calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,   1);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Finally i leave this method and i use Broadcast receiver:

[Here is solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491631/create-notification-with-broadcastreceiver)

Answer (score 0):

```
      @Override
    public void onCreate(){

     NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)       getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
 notificationIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);


      Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentTitle("PACS Notification")
                    .setContentText(Alarm Notification from Alarm Manager")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icona)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent ).build();
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            mNotificationManager .notify(0, noti);



    }
```

**Note:**
      Plz add ur service class on androidmanifest.xml as,

```
  <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".Notifications " />
```

Comment: i tried add this to manifest but it did not help.. and with your code eclipse did not recognize .build() method and yes i have updated android support library...