# How to create scheduled notifications in Android

Tags: android

i want to create notifications wherein the user input two dates and time interval.

For example: a user input 10/01/15 as START DATE and 10/02/15 as END DATE and 30 mins.

After the user set it, when the start date comes, the notification will pop up (with sounds) and in every 30 mins, the notifications sounds (just like the reminder apps) and it will stop when the END DATE comes.

My question is, it possible with that idea? if yes, can u give me a source, links, or codes? I've trying for 24 hours now looking for notes that i could really understand. I am a newbie in Android and i dont know much about notifications.  THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest I'm no expert, I 'm learning too and I did not understand very well what you want to do. Anyway, I 'd like to help you.

**1 -** I think You need to read about [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) (where you write the code for notifications and that must be run in the background).

**2 -** Maybe, You also have to read about [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) (to store the data and work with them in the future).

Then, working from information stored on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and address the core of what you are saying you are still not getting. I think you put your finger on an important aspect of programming in Android: there are always a lot of collaborators, and it's hard to know who does what and when.

When I first started doing notifications in Android, after having done iOS, I thought I had dropped into crazy land. But I came to really appreciate it.

In short: you want to look at the AlarmManager as your timer. You don't use a simple timer for a lot of reasons you can read about in the documentation for the AlarmManager. But then, when your alarm triggers, you are going to build the notification (use the new NotificationBuilder) inside the BroadcastReceiver and then trigger it.

This question shows some code: [Create Notification with BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491631/create-notification-with-broadcastreceiver).